# Can I work part-time on a H-1B visa?

Tags: working-visas, h1-visa, employment

Can I work as a part-time employee if I have a H-1B visa from another company?

I would still be working as a full-time in the sponsor company.

Answer (score 1):

No. While on H-1b status, you can only work for the employer that petitioned you for H-1b status. You are authorized to work only through [8 CFR 274a.12(b)(9)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/274a.12#b_9):

> (b) Aliens authorized for employment with a specific employer incident
> to status or parole. The following classes of aliens are authorized to
> be employed in the United States by the specific employer and subject
> to any restrictions described in the section(s) of this chapter
> indicated as a condition of their parole or of their admission in, or
> subsequent change to, the designated nonimmigrant classification. An
> alien in one of these classes is not issued an employment
> authorization document by DHS:
>
> (9) A temporary worker or trainee (H-1, H-2A, H-2B, or H-3), pursuant
> to 8 CFR 214.2(h), or a nonimmigrant specialty occupation worker
> pursuant to sections 101(a)(15)(H)(i)(b)(1), 101(a)(15)(H)(ii)(a),
> 101(a)(15)(H)(ii)(b) and INA 101(a)(15)(H)(iii) of the Act. An alien
> in this status may be employed only by the petitioner through whom the
> status was obtained. [...]

Furthermore, an employer other than the petitioning employer, that is following the rules, should not hire you, since you do not have the documents to pass the I-9 process. For your own employer, you can use your passport plus your H-1b I-94 as a List A document for the [I-9](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/i-9-paper-version.pdf), since the employer got an approval for the H-1b petition they filed for you, but that will not work for any other employer who did not petition you for H-1b.